# Fullscreen on multiple displays and swiping moves all screens

Tags: macos, display, screen, fullscreen, multi-touch

This worked up until May 16th.
Before and after updating to macOS Sierra 10.12.5 did not solve problem.

### Config / Specs:

- MacBook Pro
- Dell monitor
- iPad using Duet app

### Previous functionality

I could expand fullscreen any app/program in Mac (the green button top right) and use 3 fingers on the trackpad to toggle between 'screens' on that individual physical screen.

### Current bug

When I fullscreen an app on one display and swipe with three fingers, swiping controls all 3 physical displays. The display in question swipes to the app, but the other two displays also swipe to the right showing blank black or white backgrounds and are mouseover-able.

### Desired functionality -- the Previous Functionality

Swiping on a screen only controls that display.

Comment: Suddenly, I'm bothered by this 'bug' starting today - never experienced it earlier. macOS Catalina, 10.15.7. The setting "Displays have separate Spaces" is on (for ages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System Preferences → Mission Control and enable Displays have separate Spaces.

[image]